# Upgrade from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 fails (possibly due to a faulty graphics driver)

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-10-upgrade

A friend of mine has recently convinced me to finally go through with the upgrade to Windows 10, as it offers WSL technology. I have already spent days trying to get the update to complete, which is ridiculous, given that it takes far less time to install Linux alongside an otherwise functional Windows installation.

My ASUS N550JV laptop has 2 graphics cards (Intel HD 4600 and nVidia GeForce 750M), and the nVidia driver is suffering from an infamous "Code 43" problem. I think the latter is preventing my system from surviving the upgrade, since the error code (0xC1900101 - 0x40017) it shows at the end is normally associated with a faulty graphics driver. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Turning off VT -d in BIOS
- Disabling the nVidia driver
- Uninstalling both Intel and nVidia drivers and using Microsoft's default display driver
- Rolling both drivers back to the latest versions from the manufacturer's website
- Using a driver pack to upgrade both graphics drivers to the latest version
- Performing the installation after a ["clean boot"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows)
- Completely removing nVidia drivers and "hiding" the update for them prior to installation (the only difference it made was that the machine automatically restarted and reverted back to 8.1 by itself as opposed to me having to restart it physically)
- Placing a `PID.txt` file in the resources folder of the installation media containing the default Windows 10 Pro key
- Installing with the internet and firewall turned off

I am performing the upgrade from a USB created from the Windows 10 installation .iso file (from [Microsoft's site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)). There is no problem with the installation media, as I have been able to successfully upgrade Windows 7 Professional using it on another computer. As a matter of fact, the installation on Windows 7 (both a clean and a "dirty" one) only took 5-10 minutes. The Windows 7 machine is not a laptop and doesn't have a product key embedded into BIOS, but that's pretty much the only significant difference. When GWX was still available, I did a test upgrade on my laptop, and there were absolutely no problems with it. I fail to understand what's going on now and why.

All of this information is related to an *upgrade* from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. I cannot really perform any "destructive" approaches, such as "refreshing the PC" or doing a clean install. I would like to know if it is possible to complete the installation by modifying any of the methods I've already tried or if there is an approach I have missed that works.

Logs:

- Windows.~bt\Sources\Panther - [setuperr.log](https://pastebin.com/MGDPqT0J)
- Windows.~bt\Sources\Rollback - [setuperr.log](https://pastebin.com/BQ47paJZ)

Comment: An installation log is created, can you provide that log, so someone can diagnose your problem

Comment: @Ramhound, could you please tell me where to find it? Thank you.

Comment: I don’t have a way to do the proper research to answer that at this time.  If I were you I would do the research to provide the relevant information.  You are downloading a Windows 10 ISO, mounting the ISO with in Windows, and launching the upgrade from within Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound, the installation creates a lot of logs. It's impossible to know which ones are relevant if you don't know the particularities of the process. I have posted the ones I think *might* be relevant, but there's no way for me to tell.

Comment: That appears to be the correct log, but knowing what error code you received, would really help diagnose the problem

Comment: `$Windows.~bt\Sources\Rollback\setupapi\setupapi.dev.log` would also be helpful.

Comment: The upgrade is failing due to telemetry.  If you are attempting to perform the upgrade through GWX then that is likely the reason it's failing.  If you use the Media Creation Tool does the upgrade still fail?  Your upgrade is not failing due to a hardware problem but due to telemetry, specifically, "PidGenX function failed on this product key."

Comment: @Ramhound, I have updated the question with information about installation media and the error code I receive when installation fails. `setupapi.dev.log` doesn't exist (hidden files and system files display is turned *on*), so I cannot provide it. I do not think GWX is a thing anymore. I used the Media Creation Tool. Update failure might have something to do with me having turned off telemetry in the past, wouldn't remember what exactly I did, as it was literally years ago.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  You will have to reverse those changes.  You should get rid of the PID.txt file.  Did this machine come with Windows 7 or Windows 8.1?

Comment: @Ramhound, are you saying I will have to downgrade to Windows 8 before being able to install 10? Or were you afraid of telemetry being turned off? I got rid of the PID.txt file and tried installing with the internet and firewall turned off. Same result. The machine came with Windows 8 (Home, I think, I don't think any of them were sold with Pro at the time) and was later (legitimately) upgraded to 8.1 Pro.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have found [this article](https://www.asquaredozen.com/2018/01/16/windows-7-windows-10-fall-creators-update-1709-place-upgrade-fails-error-0xc1900204-invalid-sku/) with a seemingly similar issue described, but it hasn't really helped me.

Comment: Windows 8 Professional certainly was sold on OEM hardware.  I purchased one such device (Surface Pro 3). The changes you have to reverse are those to disable telemetry.